# Why does BroadcastReceiver retain my objects?

Tags: java, gson

Each time I call `myMethod()` on an instance of `MyObject`, a new instance is being allocated, and is not being GC'd after `myMethod()` ends.

I've been struggling with this for hours, What am I missing?

```
public class MyObject {
    public String tag = "myTag";

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            ...
        }
    };

    public MyObject() {
         LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(mReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("TEST_NOTIFICATION"));
    }

    public String serialize() {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(this, MyObject.class);
    }

    public static MyObject deserialize(String jsonString) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyObject.class);
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        String serialized = this.serialize();
        Log.d("", "serialized: " + serialized);
        MyObject mis = MyObject.deserialize(serialized);
        Log.d("", "deserialized " + mis.tag);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know it is not collected by GC?

Comment: @igreen - if I hold one instance of MyObject and call myMethod() 5 times, and then broadcast an intent with TEST_NOTIFICATION, it gets hit 5 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to GSON. `new BroadcastReceiver()` creates an instance of an anonymous class which keeps a reference to its containing `MyObject`. The `LocalBroadcastManager` in turn keeps the reference to the `mReceiver`. To fix this, define a static inner class (or top-level class) implementing `BroadcastReceiver`. Static inner classes don't keep a reference to their enclosing class.